# How to debug Bearer error="invalid_token"

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal

We are building an application with a SPA front end and an API backend.

We are using the MSAL authentication library, the frontend and backend are registered as applications in Azure AD.

We get a HTTP 401 error.

To try and debug the problem, we have taken the token from the SPA application, and put it in jwt.io, it looks fine. We have also tried sending the request from Postman, with the bearer token. Still same problem.

Is there a way to find out in what way the token is invalid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple check to get some clue why the token is not accpted, is to set this flag to true in AddJwtBearer:

```
.AddJwtBearer(opt =>
{
    opt.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
    ...
```

Doing so, will include why it was rejected in the **WWW-Authenticate** response header:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Sun, 02 Aug 2020 11:19:06 GMT
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"
```

The second step is to check the logs from the AddJwtBearer handler.

To complement this answer, I wrote a blog post that goes into more detail about this topic:
[Troubleshooting JwtBearer authentication problems in ASP.NET Core](https://nestenius.se/2023/02/21/troubleshooting-jwtbearer-authentication-problems-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but where do I add this code? I have the following line that sets up authentication

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

Comment: try AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi( opt => opt.IncludeErrorDetails = true; ...... });

Comment: It's already true by default, you can also add it in the appsettings AzureAd section.

This did not resolve the problem sorry

Comment: See the blog post I have in my answer ,my blog contains several posts about trobuleshooting auth problems. @Morten_564834 what error do you get?

Comment: Thanks for helping. I’m just getting a Bearer error="invalid_token" with no further info. I have set IncludeErrrorDetails to true (though it’s already true default), and if I write ex. a wrong clientId the error_description shows up. I have a feeling that it’s because i’m missing a clientsecret in the settings of the protected web api

Comment: APIs usually don't need clientid/secret, only the openidconnect part do. .. so hard to tell what your problem is without more context and sample code, perhaps better to create a separate question with same code?

Comment: Thanks, I've posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77236499/blazor-web-assembly-app-calling-protected-web-api