# Blazor web assembly app calling protected web api

Tags: blazor, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

Can somebody show me a working example of a blazor web assembly app (using implicit auth flow / msal 2.0) calling a protected web api.

How does the program.cs and appsettings look like?

I set things up, but I just get a  www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token" error with no further information.

This is what I have so far:

**Blazor web assembly app:**

```cs
 "AzureAd": {
   "Authority": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>",
   "ClientId": "<my-app-reg-client-id>",
   "ValidateAuthority": true
 }
```

Program.cs:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;
using SendModtag.Helper.Web;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");


builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.ProviderOptions.LoginMode = "redirect";
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("api://dev-myapp/access");
});

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

FetchData.razor:

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var tokenResult = await TokenProvider.RequestAccessToken();
    if (tokenResult.TryGetToken(out var token))
    {
        var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage()
            {
                RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:7056/WeatherForecast"),
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
            };

        // Add the token to the Authorization header
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization =
            new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.Value);

        var response = await Http.SendAsync(requestMessage);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            forecasts = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>();
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to fetch data.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Could not get an access token.");
    }

}
```

I'm able to authenticate and send a request, but I get a 401 error back with above error. Same error can be reproduced directly in swagger using the same bearer token.

**Web API setup:**

```
"AzureAd": {
  "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
  "Domain": "mydomain.onmicrosoft.com",
  "TenantId": "<my-tenant-id>",
  "ClientId": "<my-app-reg-client-id>",
  "Scopes": "api://dev-myapp/access",
  "IncludeErrorDetails": true,
  "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc" // Not sure if this is need when I only need authorization, but same error with/without
}
```

Program.cs:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{

    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: "MyApp.Cors.Policy",
                      builder =>
                      {
                          builder.WithOrigins("https://localhost:44322")
                                 .AllowAnyHeader()
                                 .AllowAnyMethod()
                                 .AllowCredentials();
                      });
});

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddCustomSwagger();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("MyApp.Cors.Policy");

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

WeatherForecastController.cs:

```cs
[Authorize]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
[RequiredScope(RequiredScopesConfigurationKey = "AzureAd:Scopes")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
    {
        "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
    };

    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
        {
            Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
            TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
            Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
        })
        .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Using .NET 8 RC1

[image]

Comment: call the WeatherForecastController API without Authorize/RequiredScope and print out what the User object contains. See https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/IdentityServer/blob/main/hosts/main/LocalApiController.cs 

Also add a sample copy of the access token to the question.